# SUM and Pivot in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I currently have a table with individual transaction prices listed by SID:

```
+-----+-----------+
| SID | Item Cost |
+-----+-----------+
| 001 | $1.50     |
| 002 | $2.25     |
| 003 | $3.50     |
| 002 | $5.80     |
| 002 | $1.00     |
| 003 | $20.00    |
+-----+-----------+
```

I also have a query that lists transactions by SID, where items match a specific type (AlaCarte), and indicates the price of each item.

```
SELECT April2013.SID, April2013.Price, MenuItems.MealType
FROM April2013 LEFT JOIN MenuItems ON MenuItems.Item = April2013.Item
WHERE MenuItems.MealType = 'AlaCarte';
```

I'd like to list these by SID, such that there will be a list of each SID, and all the transactions for each SID are summed up.

```
+-----+-------------------------+
| SID | Sum of all Transactions |
+-----+-------------------------+
| 001 | $1.50                   |
| 002 | $45.00                  |
| 003 | $23.25                  |
+-----+-------------------------+
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am missing something you should be able to use the following which applies the aggregate function `sum()` with a `GROUP BY` the `SID`:

```
SELECT April2013.SID, Sum(April2013.Price) Total
FROM April2013 
INNER JOIN MenuItems 
  ON MenuItems.Item = April2013.Item
WHERE MenuItems.MealType = 'AlaCarte'
GROUP BY April2013.SID;
```

You will notice that I changed your query from a LEFT JOIN to an INNER JOIN because you have a filter on the WHERE clause for MenuItems. This will return only the matching rows in both tables.

If you want to return all `April2013` rows, then you will alter the LEFT JOIN query to the following which moves the WHERE filter to the JOIN condition.:

```
SELECT April2013.SID, Sum(April2013.Price) Total
FROM April2013 
LEFT JOIN MenuItems 
  ON MenuItems.Item = April2013.Item
  AND MenuItems.MealType = 'AlaCarte'
GROUP BY April2013.SID;
```